# LinkedIn Wherehows - how to start backend?

Tags: java, gradle, playframework, linkedin-api

I cloned repo https://github.com/linkedin/WhereHows.git but can not start backend.

This is a script (runBackend):

```
#!/bin/bash
set -a
source application.env
set +a

export JAVA_OPTS="-Xms512m -Xmx2048m -Dhttp.port=9001"

build/stage/wherehows-backend/bin/playBinary
```

Trying to run:

```
cd WhereHows/wherehows-backend
./runBackend
```

**error**:

```
./runBackend: line 8: build/stage/wherehows-backend/bin/playBinary: No such file or directory
```

This is a file (application.env) where apparently in line 8 error is comming from (WHZ_DB_DRIVER="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"):

```
# Directory containing kerberos config files
WHZ_KRB5_DIR="/dir/to/krb5conf"

# Secret Key
WHZ_SECRET="change_me"

# Database Connection
WHZ_DB_DRIVER="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
WHZ_DB_USERNAME="wherehows"
WHZ_DB_PASSWORD="wherehows"
# Fully qualified jdbc url
WHZ_DB_URL="jdbc:mysql://localhost/wherehows"

#mysql setup
WHZ_DB_DSCLASSNAME="com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource"
WHZ_DB_DIALECT="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLInnoDBDialect"

# Directory containing ETL job files
WHZ_ETL_JOBS_DIR="/var/tmp/jobs"

# Temp directory for ETL job
WHZ_ETL_TEMP_DIR="/var/tmp/wherehows"
```

How to fix this?

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that the application.env file has anything to do with the error as it seems to be complaining about the directory specified in the runBackend script.

In any case, you do not use the runBackend script (and if you inspect the wherehows-backend dir., you see that there is no /bin folder that runBackend refers to, which is giving you the error). You need to

```
cd wherehows-frontend
../gradlew runPlayBinary
```

This is for a dev. build anyway (can see the docs for how to run the deployment buld similarly).
(These instructions are from the github docs for the project https://github.com/linkedin/WhereHows/blob/master/wherehows-docs/getting-started.md#frontend-setup).